# How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?

Tags: string, xpath, xslt, case-conversion

How do you do case conversion in XSL?

```
<xsl:variable name="upper">UPPER CASE</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lower" select="???"/>
```

Answer (score 216, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 the `upper-case()` and `lower-case()` functions are not available. 
If you're using a 1.0 stylesheet the common method of case conversion is `translate()`:

```
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />


<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(doc, $lowercase, $uppercase)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is there a Unicode version?  This solution is not going to work with funny characters...

Comment: For XSLT 1.0 you'd have to add more to the smallcase/uppercase variables or use an extension function.

Comment: If you decided not to use the extention function you might be able to make a complete list using the Unicode Character Database: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UCD.html

Comment: Here is the complete ANSI table: translate(%s, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ')

Answer (score 49):

XSLT 2.0 has `upper-case()` and `lower-case()` functions. In case of XSLT 1.0, you can use `translate()`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate("xslt", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")" />
```

Answer (score 10):

.NET XSLT implementation allows to write custom managed functions in the stylesheet. For lower-case() it can be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:utils="urn:myExtension" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="utils" language="C#">
    <![CDATA[
      public string ToLower(string stringValue)
      {
        string result = String.Empty;

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        {
          result = stringValue.ToLower(); 
        }

        return result;
      }
    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <!-- using of our custom function -->
  <lowercaseValue>
    <xsl:value-of select="utils:ToLower($myParam)"/>
  </lowercaseValue>
```

Assume, that can be slow, but still acceptable.

Do not forget to enable embedded scripts support for transform:

```cs
// Create the XsltSettings object with script enabled.
XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

// Load stylesheet
xslt.Load(xsltPath, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

Comment: This solution will work with any characters, even weird Unicode ones.  This worked great for me, but I simplified the method body to `return (stringValue ?? string.Empty).ToLower();`. Thanks @Vladislav, I never knew you could do that!

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:variable name="upper">UPPER CASE</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lower" select="translate($upper,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
<xsl:value-of select ="$lower"/>

//displays UPPER CASE as upper case
```

Answer (score 1):

upper-case(string) and lower-case(string)

Comment: These are only in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

For ANSI character encoding:

```
 translate(//variable, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ')
```