# lower case the first character of a string using only xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have seen [patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt) for translating a string into lower (or upper case) using the translate function for folks stuck using xslt 1.0.

Is there a elegant way of just making the first letter of a string lowercase?

```
TestCase => testCase
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your string were, for example, in an attribute called `name`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(@name, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), substring(@name, 2))"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to combine [substring](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/W3C/xpath.html#function-substring) and [concat](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/W3C/xpath.html#function-concat) with translate to do it like so:

```
concat(translate(substring(s,1,1), $smallcase, $uppercase),substring(s,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the XPath `translate` function, having separated the string into first character and the rest. This will require somewhat long winded XSLT using multiple variables to hold intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has a substring function, so you could use that pattern with the substring function to get what you want.