# XSLT- Get substring and pass it as parameters to java function

Tags: xslt

In the below code snippet, I am trying to get the substring of my @imageMeta node, append some more path location and pass it as a parameter to my java method through XSLT.

```
<xsl:variable name="imagePathFrom" select="/config/assets/images/{substring-after(@imageMeta,'/')}" />
<xsl:variable name="imagePathTo" select="'/dev/svn_root/platform/system'" />
<xsl:value-of select="filecopy:copyFile($imagePathFrom, $imagePathTo)"/>
```

My `@imageMeta` node data looks like `Images/common/dialog/dialogue_black.png`.
I have to convert the above path to `images/common/dialog/dialogue_black.png` (note the change of capital 'I' to small 'i') and append some more path data.

So my final path entry should look like "/config/assets/images/common/dialog/dialogue_black.png". When i run my code snippet i get an error stating:

```
line 51: Error parsing XPath expression '/config/assets/images/{substring-after(@imageMeta,'/')}'.'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="imagePathFrom" select="/config/assets/images/{substring-after(@imageMeta,'/')}" />
> ```

**There are two problems here**:

1. A syntax error -- a `select` is probably the only attribute attribute in XSLT that cannot contain an AVT.
2. Even without the AVT, this would attempt to select all `/config/assets/images` nodes, but the intent is that the variable must contain the *string* `"/config/assets/images"`

**Solution to both problems**:

```
<xsl:variable name="imagePathFrom" select=
 "concat('/config/assets/images/', substring-after(@imageMeta,'/')" />
```

**Alternative solution**:

```
<xsl:variable name="imagePathFrom" select=
 "concat('/config/assets/',
         translate(substring(@imageMeta, 1, 1),
                   $vUpper,
                   $vLower
                   ),
         substring(@imageMeta, 2)
         )" />
```

where `$vLower` and `$vUpper` are defined, respectively, as:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

and

```
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Comment: @nishMaria: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Could you, please, consider *accepting* it (by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer)?

Answer (score 2):

There is one problem in your code:
`<xsl:variable name="imagePathFrom" select="/config/assets/images/{substring-after(@imageMeta,'/')}" />`

It suppose to be ..
`<xsl:variable name="imagePathFrom" select="substring-after(/config/assets/images/@imageMeta,'/')" />`

Comment: This suggestion fixes the syntax, but it is not the correct one: `/config/assets/images` is the disk path, not a path in the source XML, Dimitre solution is the right one

Answer (score 0):

infant programmer 'Aravind' suggestion will solve your parse error.

You also mentioned you wanted to lower-case the capital i. Two options here:

- Using XSLT 1.0, this StackOverflow answer explains how to [lower-case the first character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655284/lower-case-the-first-character-of-a-string-using-only-xslt-1-0). It won't work for Unicode characters such as 'Í' but you probably don't need it.
- XSLT 2.0 has a `lower-case` function, which will lower-case your **entire string**, and may not be what you're looking for.