# How to change first letter to lowercase using XPath or XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb-4.8.1.

I wish to change my request first letter to lowercase.
I am getting request parameters like this:

```
 <property name="Methodname" expression="//name/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

In this way I am getting names like

**GetDetails, CallQuerys, ChangeService...**

Whereas I wish to change all the names to be like this:

**getDetails, callQuerys, changeService...**

If I wanted to upper or lower the case of the entire name, I could use XPath's `fn:upper-case()` and `fn:lower-case()` functions, but my requirement is different.

How can I change all the *first letters* only to lowercase?

Is it possible with XPath or XSLT?

Comment: how can i use fn:lower-case() in an expression? using it like this:  <property expression="{fn:lower-case(get-property('MARKET'))}" name="LOWERCASE_MARKET" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     gives an error: Invalid XPath expression for attribute 'expression'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**XPath 1.0:**

```
<property name="Methodname" scope="default" type="STRING" 
          expression="concat(translate(substring(//name/text(), 1, 1), 
                                       'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 
                             substring(//name/text(), 2))"/>
```

**XPath 2.0:**

```
<property name="Methodname" scope="default" type="STRING" 
          expression="concat(lower-case(substring(//name/text(), 1, 1)), 
                             substring(//name/text(), 2))"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to `kjhughes` answer / this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/655333/314291), you'll probably want to use this in conjunction with the identity transform to copy the remainder of the document unscathed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@name[ancestor::property]">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(., 1, 1), 
                           'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                           'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), substring(., 2))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```