# XSLT Stylesheet: Changing text to upper case

Tags: xslt, coding-style, uppercase

I am using an XSLT stylesheet to create an Excel document from an XML file. One of the values that I am pulling in I want to display as upper case. How is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 has fn:upper-case() and fn:lower-case() functions. However in case you are using of XSLT 1.0, you can use translate():

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(doc, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1, though it's the same strategy as my answer keeping variables of the letters is certainly a more reusable solution.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful and easy :)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `translate()` function in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(//some-xpath,
                                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
```

If you're lucky enough to have access to XSLT 2.0, you can use the `upper-case()` function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="upper-case(//some-xpath)"/>
```

See the [XPath function reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) for more details.

Comment: Asker's name looks vaguely French... what happens to é ? (sorry, I couldn't resist...)

Comment: @AakashM: That's the problem with the `translate()` function. You have to specify all of these things yourself. `upper-case()` is a much better option but it's not supported widely enough.

Answer (score 3):

XPath 2.0 has [`fn:upper-case()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-upper-case), which also does Unicode correct case mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Assembly like this:

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="user" language="C#">
<!--{%assembly%}-->
<![CDATA[  

public string ToUpper(string stringValue)
{
    string result = String.Empty;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
    {
      result = stringValue.ToUpper(); 
    }

    return result;
}
]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Call it as follows: `select="user:ToUpper(//root/path)"`

This can be used in 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score -7):

The easiest and cleanest way to achieve case transforms is by the means of CSS.

build a class, like:

```
.upper { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

then use the class as span class:

```
<span class="upper">
    <xsl:value-of select="myTextField" />
</span>
```

that's it :)

You can also use other transforms:

```
text-transform:  capitalize | uppercase | lowercase | none | inherit
```

Comment: I believe the OP was creating an Excel file; not HTML.

Comment: You can create Excel files by way of HTML.  I believe it will honor CSS, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The solutions does not permit case-insensitive comparison of text elements in the document - which is often the reason for forcing text into a single, consistent, case. This solution will only apply to the output rendering of the result.

Comment: "I am using an XSLT stylesheet" is the key here. @iconoclast Yes you can (not a shameless plug, I swear): http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html