# How do I translate a complete document to lower case before applying any other templates?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSL transformation where I used to query a string that way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/input/as/a[@id=$id]/CaMeL[@id2=$id2]/@interest"/>
```

Now, it happened that `CaMeL` (in the XML) shall be renamed to `cAmEl`. Fine. Simply chaning the case in my transform would immediately work but I would lose backward compatibilty.

Searching at SO, I found this: [XSLT Stylesheet: Changing text to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207098/xslt-stylesheet-changing-text-to-upper-case)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207141/520162) looks promising but I'm currently stuck at how to fill the `doc` parameter used in the answer.

**How could I add a translation step in my existing `<xsl:template match="/">` that translates the whole doc to lower case before any other templates are going to be applied?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help. But I didn't test it. Could you provide some sample XML?

```
<xsl:value-of select="/input/as/a[@id=$id]/*[translate(local-name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='camel' and @id2=$id2]/@interest"/>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to change your whole XML file to lower case (without elements and attributes values of course) you can use this following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having done the conversion to lower-case, you can try to create multi-pass XSLT traformation - the next pass would be your conversion. However, I'm not sure how to do it using XSLT 1.0.

**EDIT 2**

OK, so here comes the whole example. I didn't have your examples so I worked on my own ones.

Sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<baba>aaa</baba>
<Baba>BBB</Baba>
</Root>
```

XSLT with multi-pass sorting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="firstPassResult">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="firstPass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="firstPass">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="firstPass">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$firstPassResult" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//baba" mode="secondPass">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I works under Altova XMLSpy debugger. Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>aaaBBB
```

Comment: multi-pass? sounds interesting. tell me more :-) how do I do it?

Comment: Perfect! I used XSL since years now but never used a **mode**. Thank you!