# XML Need to change case of imported data

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Exporting a csv, need to change the customer postcodes to uppercase.

I've tried searching for the answer and found the following:

[XSLT Stylesheet: Changing text to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207098/xslt-stylesheet-changing-text-to-upper-case)

But this only works for known values or something? My code is as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="sepstart" select="'&#34;'"/> <!-- &#34; field start seperator, including '' -->
<xsl:variable name="sepend" select="'&#34;,'"/> <!-- field end seperator, including '' -->

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>"eBay Username","Name","Postcode","Address","SKU","Samples Wanted","Order id"</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">


<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="concat(shipping/firstname,shipping/lastname)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="shipping/postcode"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />
<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" /><xsl:value-of select="concat(shipping/street1,', ',shipping/street2,', ',shipping/city)"/><xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />

<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" />
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">
<xsl:value-of select="sku"/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />

<xsl:value-of select="$sepstart" />
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">
<xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="$sepend" />


<xsl:value-of select="increment_id"/>


<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>


</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</file>
</files>
```

Postcodes are here:

```
<xsl:value-of select="shipping/postcode"/>
```

Is this possible? You can't quickly change to uppercase in excel either, this is a daily export (and I need anyone to be able to do it!)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this only works for known values". There are no case-changing functions in XSLT 1.0, so you need to enumerate the characters you want to be affected. That is the problem with the solution you linked to: it won't work with diacritics, for example.

Comment: I clearly haven't a clue with this. It's only UK postcodes, so it's standard abc's.
Also I've tried the solution above but I don't know how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I've tried the solution above but I don't know how to get it to
>   work.

**Step 1:**

Place these two variables at the top of your stylesheet, outside of any template:

```
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
```

**Step 2:**

Replace this part:

```
<xsl:value-of select="shipping/postcode"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(shipping/postcode, $lowercase, $uppercase)"/>
```

**Step 3:**

Report your progress here.

--
Unrelated to your question, but it looks like your stylesheet could do with some streamlining to avoid the repetitive parts - perhaps by calling a named template to create the "field"?