# Compare two strings for equality ignoring case in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to check if a value matches a certain string, and the input may be in any case.

```xml
<xsl:if test="$adminStatus='Down'">
  do something
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `translate()` function on both `$adminStatus` and target value.

[How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`translate`](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/06/05/transforming.html) function to convert all upper case to lower case.

```xml
<xsl:if test="translate($adminStatus, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'down'">
  do something
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: this is wrong..  you try to translate the lowercase letters to uppercase in order to match a lowercase word. -1

Comment: @Treemonkey fixed now.