# How to transform an xml file by searching for some nodes and replacing the values

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

This is the input xml -

```
<payload id="001">
    <termsheet>
          <format>PDF</format>
          <city>New York</city>
    </termsheet>
</payload>
```

We are using Xalan for most of our xml transformations and we are on XSLT 1.0
I want to write a XSLT template which would convert the input to the below output  -

```
<payload id="001">
    <termsheet>
          <format>pdf</format>
          <city>Mr. ABC</city>
    </termsheet>
</payload>
```

I tried lot of answers on SO, but can't get around this problem.

---

Apologies for not being clear, toLower was an over simplification. I want to use the city name and invoke a java method which will return a business contact from that city. I have updated the original question

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053828/lowercase-conversion-in-xsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest way is to use java extension with Xalan, you can write a simple java class  that implements the business logic you need, and then call it from your xslt. The stylesheet is quite simple

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:template match='node() | @*'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ='node()|@*'></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="termsheet/city">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select='java:org.example.Card.getName(.)'/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you also neeed to write the java class invoked

```
package org.example

public class Card {

  public static String getName(String id) {
     // put here your code to get what you need 
     return "Mr. ABC"
  }
}
```

there are other ways to do that and you should really give an eye to the documentation about [xalan extensions](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#java-namespace)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I was struggling with the xpath matching and your solution worked so well. 

Is there a way to avoid specifying <city> tag manually and derive it using xslt?

Comment: I guess you are thinking to the <xsl:copy> instruction, I updated the answer.