# Make string lowercase XSLT

Tags: xslt

How do I convert a string to lowercase in XSLT? I'm really a noob at it, and I know you use the lower-case function, but what's an example of it in use? Do I use `<fn:lowercase>StRiNg</fn>` or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt)

Comment: Totally duplicate. And examples are present in question @Alejandro linked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To put you out of your misery, and ignoring protocol regarding duplicate questions,

```
<xsl:value-of select='lower-case(@prototype)'/>
```

Comment: This requires XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread
[How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt)

Also XPath function reference will be useful http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp

---

Ahmed Hashim

Comment: If this is a duplicate, don't you think that yours should be a comment, not an answer?