# How to use lower-case() function in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt-2.0

In a small XML conversion project I am working on, I am able to use the XSLT 1.0 `translate()` function to convert to lowercase or uppercase as suggested in posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt), so that something like the following works fine:

```
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@value, $uppercase, $lowercase)" />
```

But really, I would prefer to use XSLT 2.0's `lower-case()` function, but for the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="lower-case(@value)" />
```

...Chrome outputs nothing, and Firefox gets "unknown" error 0x8060000e, which maybe suggests that the `lower-case()` function isn't recognized. Perhaps my problem is something with the XML declaration line?:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

...or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Probably neither Chrome nor Firefox support XSLT 2?

Comment: @Jim Garrison Huh... I just assumed it was a given that today's fast-changing browsers supported a 4 year-old standard, but [apparently not](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/59378-browser-support-xslt-2-0-a.html). Anyway, if you want to make your comment into an answer I'll give you the points for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Chrome nor Firefox support XSLT2, in spite of its being a 4-year old standard.  See for example [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=370173), languishing since 2008.

Comment: Again, thanks for the tip. For this project I ended up using [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) for the heavy lifting anyway, but I miss the convenience of developing in the browser.

Comment: XSLT 2 with Saxon can now be used in the browser also with the Saxon-CE processor.