# Umbraco NiceUrl ToLower

Tags: xslt, umbraco, tolower

I'm trying to change the URL to lower in my href tag, here is my code:

```
<a href="{$url}{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/{$AppendedID}/">
```

I've tried using `Exslt.ExsltStrings:lowercase(node-set)` with no joy as this throws an error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: [This post][1] might help, as it deals with changing case in XSLT


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt

Answer (score 2):

The following expression should work:

```
Exslt.ExsltStrings:lowercase(concat($url, umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id), '/', $AppendedID, '/'))
```

Testing with the following piece of code ....

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="'http://www.EXAMPLE.com'" />
    <xsl:variable name="AppendedID" select="123" />
    <a href="{Exslt.ExsltStrings:lowercase(concat($url, umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id), '/', $AppendedID, '/'))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
    </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

.... the rendered HTML should be along the lines of ....

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/some-page.aspx/123/">Some Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know direct way to solve this except using `Exslt.ExsltStrings:lowercase(node-set)`

but is this throw error when you use it with `umbraco.library:NiceUrl` then you may try to make the string lower and store it in temp variable then use this temp variable directly.