# Extract Domino database meta-data and data types

Tags: lotus-domino

I have to investigate taking a domino database to an alternative database - probably SQL Server or Oracle.  How do I investigate and output a complete easily readable report on the domino database's meta-data, including all data field types and imbedded objects, such as other files, imbedded text and images etc?

I have looked at creating the database synopsis but I need something that doesn't contain all the unnecessary information etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own tool using the [NotesNoteCollection class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESNOTECOLLECTION_CLASS.html) and the [NotesDXLExporter class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDXLEXPORTER_CLASS.html), parsing out whatever parts you consider necessary and leaving out the parts you think are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks.  This might be an option although we are no longer allowed to spend time developing around Domino.  I will look into it

Comment: If you know or are willing to learn XSL then this is probably the way to go because you're not allowed to do  domino development yet you're going to have to transfer this data somewhere. This will be an important skillset for you. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045313/how-to-export-lotus-notes-documents-both-parent-and-response-forms-to-xml/43190706#43190706 Also, ***beware***: Don't assume data types are uniform for all docs.I guarantee you that you'll come across a date field that on ONE document is stored as text, or something like that.

Comment: If you're not allowed to do development, there are some companies selling migration tools out there that include "analysis". One of these might do what you want, but I've not used them so I can't really give you any help. In any case, StackOverflow is intended for software development questions. that's why I answered as I did. If you want information about tools to aid in your migration, you might be better off asking in ServerFault.