# Upper-case integration in existing code (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt

How correctly add an "upper-case" expression in already working XSLT code?

**sample:**

```
  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <Document  ABC="{element1/@attr1}{element2/@attr2}"
               DEF="{normalize-space(concat(element1/@attr-3, element1/element2/@attr4, ' ',element1/element2/@attr5, ' '))}"
               GHI="{element3/@attr6}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>
```

**need** **to up**
  ABC, DEF, GHI' s values

Or, its better (or equal) to make this upper-case by the separate template?
  interesting in both possibilities

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is. I would probably use some variables for code readability, but just adding translate() on top of what you have would work too. Seems like you're asking for opinions, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 or more you can simply use the upper-case() method.

Example:

```
ABC="{upper-case(element1/@attr1)}{upper-case(element2/@attr2)}"
```

Or in XSLT 1.0, refer to this answer: [How can I convert a string to upper- or lower-case with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586231/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-upper-or-lower-case-with-xslt)